# GORM+Hibernate: Insert foreign key only

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, mapping, grails-orm

I have a domain entity like this:

```
class MyEntity{
    AnotherEntity anotherEntity

    static mapping{
        anotherEntity column: 'ANOTHER_ENTITY_ID', ignoreNotFound: true
    }
}

class AnotherEntity{
    long AnotherEntityId
    string SomethingElse
}
```

When I save an instance of `MyEntity` I want to also persist the foreign key for `AnotherEntity` inside MyEntity's table without having to go through AnotherEntity's validation or persistence.  If I map it as `insertable: false` then nothing persists.

Comment: You can very well have the id only instead the entity altogether. `MyEntity` should have `Long anotherEntityId` mapped to corresponding column instead of `anotherEntity`. That way you bypassed the entity validation and persistence.

Comment: @dmahapatro I already tried that, and it works in most cases.  However, I'd like to know if that can be avoided.